# how to create this ui in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image: design]

I need to create this screen in my app I have completed the top part  but I am stuck making the bottom part the rotating rounded scale. Anyone has experience with similar designs or could offer guidance on best practices, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Code examples, suggestions, or any form of help would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: U can use some libirary like https://pub-web.flutter-io.cn/packages/gauge_indicator or any others. Or u need to use `CustomPaint`.

Comment: see [_SizedContentScrollableExample1](https://gist.github.com/pskink/5fd59d240beb8dd9d780f978e5c76b3c#file-sized_content_scrollable-dart-L250)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Nayana check this package from syncfusion
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges. Basically, you have to create a gauge view in Flutter to achieve your requirement. Without plugins, we can do that but it deals with lot of calculations with customPaint and Animation concepts. Will try to share, if I found any other example, which was really close to your UI.